# How do I unlock Joe's life raft in Deep Loot?

Tags: deep-loot

It says "Sing along with Joe". What does that mean? Has anyone found out how to unlock it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://toucharcade.com/community/threads/deep-loot-by-monster-and-monster.234818/page-27#post-3317983):

> It should unlock **after watching the credits**

Comment: Can confirm, it works after finishing the credits. Once they finish you hit the back button to get to the homescreen and the ship is unlocked.